# Check in for Iceland Air from Aberdeen

Tags: air-travel, usa, online-resources, icelandair, abz

I'm travelling from Aberdeen to Denver via Keflavik, with Icelandair and I'm a bit puzzled about how to check in and how to choose my seat.

On the Icelandair website it says that online check in is not available from Aberdeen and that the flight is operated by Air Iceland. Air Iceland's webpage doesn't seem to have online check in.

My question is: is the only way to check in at the airport? If so, is there some way for me to choose my seat before arriving at the airport?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If no online check in is available then the only way to check in is at the airport.

According to [Iceland Air website](http://www.icelandair.us/information/customer-support/faq/) it is possible to choose seats during the booking process, however there is no info on seat change. It might be possible to change the seat on the website\by calling an agent however the seat you choose is not guaranteed until check in according to several threads including [this one](http://www.flyertalk.com/forum/other-european-airlines/1572097-icelandair-seat-change.html).

The process for choosing a seat online is detailed in [this thread](https://www.tripadvisor.com/ShowTopic-g189970-i594-k8818353-Iceland_Air_Seat_Selection_Proceedure-Reykjavik_Capital_Region.html) by a customer.

> I have found on the site where to request seats (I DO understand that it is a request only and have seen on previous forum answers that the seats can change).
>
> I went onto Icelandair's home page and clicked on 'My Trips'.
>
> Enter your flight reference and surname and on the next page you will see 'seat preferences' in blue. Click on that and follow the instructions.

Comment: That's really helpful, unfortunately I get "The seat map is not available for this flight." when I try to select a seat for the Aberdeen to Keflavik and for Keflavik to Denver every single seat is showing as occupied :(

Comment: It might be too close to the flight to choose seats if online check in could have already started. I know this happens on other airlines

Comment: Good point, but I'm not leaving for a couple of weeks, your answer I was still very helpful though.

Comment: I just spoke to Icelandair customer services and apparently there is no way to preselect seats or check in before arriving at the airport for the flight from Aberdeen to Keflavik, and all the seats on the flight from Keflavik to Denver have already been reserved. I don't really understand the latter because I have a confirmed reservation on the flight but can't choose a seat.

Comment: You might have a seat automatically reserved for you in the system even though you didn't choose it.

Comment: Good point, I hadn't thought of that.